# Courses etc. for developing an automated trading algorithm?

Tags: analysis, trading, algorithmic-trading

Does anyone know of any courses etc for teaching people how to learn how to apply technical analysis and trading mechanics to the development of an automated trading algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a regular at [Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com/), and attended the most recent [Quantcon](http://www.quantcon.com/). They had some seminars, but largely it's a huge topic (like learning "surgery") because of the multiple disciplines involved.

Different languages, different levels of profeciency with those languages, different time frames, different securities, and a general air of secrecy where no one wants to share strategies.

For a programmer, I'd focus on API integrations (if you need that, some strategies run once a month then you punch in your trades manually). For a noob-programmer, I'd focus on programming skills in C#.

Sorry for being so broad, but like I said it's a huge topic. There's miles between a long gamma hedge fund doing managed futures and an HFT with custom hardware chips.